# Не могу выполнить Http запрос на локальный сервер Android

Tags: java, android

Возникла проблема, я создал класс `HttpActivity.java`:

```
public class HttpActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
                URL url = null; // Иницилизируем объект ссылки на сервер
                try {
                        url = new URL(urls[0]); // Даем правильное значение переменной
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace(); // В случае ошибки выводим причину
                }
                HttpURLConnection connection = null; // Иницилизируем объект подключения
                try {
                        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Даем правильное значение перменной
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace(); // В случае ошибки выводим причину
                }
                connection.setConnectTimeout(5000); // Устанавливаем лимит в подключении
                try {
                        connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); // Устанавливаем GET запрос
                        connection.connect(); // Подключаемся
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace(); // В случае ошибки выводим причину
                }
                return "Connected";
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        }
}
```

И вызываю из `MainActivity.java`:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.startBtn:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                break;

            case R.id.stopPauseVid:
                HttpActivity httpActivity = new HttpActivity();
                httpActivity.execute("http://192.168.0.6:5000/1234/code/1");
        }
    }
```

Но запроса на сервере я не вижу, и в LogCat пусто.
В `AndroidManifest` стоит `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` с `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`, ну никак не могу разобраться с отправкой GET запроса на сервер

Comment: Странно, что не работает. Убедитесь, что верно IP адрес, порт и прочее указали. Ну и попробуйте выкинуть AsyncTask и HttpURLConnection, заменив их на OkHttp либу например. Код получится проще и, возможно, это поможет найти причину проблемы.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, мне только один запрос необходимо отправить на сервер, а использовать OkHttp значит нагрузить размер APK

Comment: Предложение сменить либу - это дополнительное предложение. Для начала надо проверить то, что я в начале коммента описал.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, если я пропустил это сразу - значит все верно

Comment: ИМХО, это совсем не очевидно, но ладно. Других идей о том, в чём проблема у меня нет. Разве что у вас, может быть onClick вообще не вызывается.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, проверил работу onClick - он в порядке

Comment: А как вы проверяете? Тот же onClick и то что на сервере нет запроса? Пробовали curl-ом и/или Postman-ом этот запрос отсылать? Может у вас сервер не работает?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да, я при переходе на ссылку все работает. onClick работает - я решил  так потому что создал лог в LogCat.

Comment: В таком случае я виду для вас два пути. Ждать что кто-то ещё увидит вопрос и поможет ответом/советом или таки попробовать OkHttp библиотеку как я предлагаю. Ещё можно попробовать на другой версии ОС запустить. Возможно это сработает и тогда я может быть буду знать в чем возможная причина проблемы. Если будете пробовать -надеюсь напиши подробно о результатах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Моя проблема решилась добавлением взаимодействий с сайтом

```
Log.d("HtppActivity", "Code - " + connection.getResponseCode());
    if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        Log.d("HttpActivity", "Content - " + connection.getContent());
    }
```